# Flutter BottomNavigationBar with AnimatedContainer - what is causing a RenderFlex overflow error?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

My Flutter app uses a BottomNavigationBar wrapped in an AnimatedContainer. When the animation takes place (activated by scrolling the list) a RenderFlex overflow error occurs. I can't work out what is causing this to happen.

I've stripped down the project to bare bones code in the hope that someone could try it out and identify the issue.

The main class:

```
class TestMain extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestMain({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestMain> createState() => _TestMain();
}

class BottomNavBarItemData {
  String label;Icon icon;Widget screen;
  BottomNavBarItemData({required this.label,required this.icon,required this.screen});
}

late ScrollController mainScrollController;

class _TestMain extends State<TestMain> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  bool _isVisible = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _isVisible = true;
    mainScrollController = ScrollController();
    mainScrollController.addListener(() {
      if (mainScrollController.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse) {
        setState(() {
          _isVisible = false;
        });
      }
      if (mainScrollController.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.forward) {
        setState(() {
          _isVisible = true;
        });
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  final List<BottomNavBarItemData> screens = [
    BottomNavBarItemData(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.home, size: 25.0, color: Colors.red),
      label: 'Page1',
      screen: const Screen1(),
    ),
    BottomNavBarItemData(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.home, size: 25.0, color: Colors.red),
      label: 'Page2',
      screen: const Screen2(),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      extendBody: true,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: IndexedStack(
          index: _selectedIndex,
          children: [
            ...screens.map((e) => e.screen).toList(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
        height: _isVisible ? 70 : 0.0,
        child: SizedBox(
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
            selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
            selectedFontSize: 14,
            unselectedFontSize: 14,
            unselectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            onTap: _onItemTapped,
            items: screens.map((e) => BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    label: e.label,
                    icon: e.icon,
                  ),
                ).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

And the two screens called by the main class:

```
class Screen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Screen1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Screen1> createState() => _Screen1();
}

class _Screen1 extends State<Screen1> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: mainScrollController,
        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column(children: [
          Container(height: 150, color: Colors.blue),
          Container(height: 150, color: Colors.white),
          Container(height: 150, color: Colors.blue),
          Container(height: 150, color: Colors.white),
          Container(height: 150, color: Colors.blue),
          Container(height: 150, color: Colors.white),
        ],),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Screen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Screen2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Screen2> createState() => _Screen2();
}

class _Screen2 extends State<Screen2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Container gets overflow because the inner item space is greater to the animation size, like on 35 it will show the overflow. You can use different animation, but it will be little difference.

You can use `SizeTransition` for this case

```dart
class _TestMain extends State<TestMain> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  bool _isVisible = true;

  late final AnimationController _controller = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    vsync: this,
  )..forward();
  late final Animation<double> _animation = CurvedAnimation(
    parent: _controller,
    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
  );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _isVisible = true;
    mainScrollController = ScrollController();
    mainScrollController.addListener(() {
      if (mainScrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
          ScrollDirection.reverse) {
        _controller.reverse();
        setState(() {
          _isVisible = false;
        });
      }
      if (mainScrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
          ScrollDirection.forward) {
        _controller.forward();
        setState(() {
          _isVisible = true;
        });
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  final List<BottomNavBarItemData> screens = [
    BottomNavBarItemData(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.home, size: 25.0, color: Colors.red),
      label: 'Page1',
      screen: const Screen1(),
    ),
    BottomNavBarItemData(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.home, size: 25.0, color: Colors.red),
      label: 'Page2',
      screen: const Screen2(),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      extendBody: true,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: IndexedStack(
          index: _selectedIndex,
          children: [
            ...screens.map((e) => e.screen).toList(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: SizeTransition(
        sizeFactor: _animation,
        child: SizedBox(
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
            selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
            selectedFontSize: 14,
            unselectedFontSize: 14,
            unselectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            onTap: _onItemTapped,
            items: screens
                .map(
                  (e) => BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    label: e.label,
                    icon: e.icon,
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

or

```dart
 bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedScale(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
        scale: _isVisible ? 1 : 0.0,
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. Yes, it gets rid of the overflow error, but has a couple of other strange behaviours. 1) The bottom bar is not showing by default, how can I fix that? 2) It doesn't hide as soon as I start scrolling, but only once I reach the end of the scroll. (I also had to switch the forward and reverse around to get it close to what I want!)

Comment: I've forgot to forward on initState. try this now

Comment: I changed the animation to Curves.easeInBack, and I had to check if the animation was already animating ( if(_controller.isAnimating) return;) but your answer definitely set me on the right path, thanks!